# r - writing a function that includes for i loop

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I scanned similar questions previously answered but couldn't find the thread that is specific to my problem.

I have a number of datasets that all have five flagging columns (binary) at the end.
The aim is to produce an output that summarises the specified column in each dataset by each flag.
Hence, each output is a list of five summary tables.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

## mydataset1

mydataset1 <- tibble(id = 1:100,
                     column_000 = sample(1:16, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     flag1 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     flag2 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     flag3 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     flag4 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     flag5 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE)) 




## summary table function

get_table <- function(data, column) {

data %>%
  # select the flag
  filter(data[[i]] == 1) %>%

  # summary table
  tabyl(column) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  top_n(5, n)

}



## list of tables function

output_list <- function(data, column) {


  # empty list
  output <- list()

  # for loop - go through each flagging column
  for (i in (length(data)-4):length(data)) {
    output[[i]] <- get_table(data, column)
  }

  # for some reason, there are NULL list items for all other columns
  output <- compact(output)
  
  # rename and print
  names(output) <- names(data)[(length(data)-4):length(data)]
  print(output)


}


### execute

output_list(mydataset1, "column_000")
# error


### manually executing the function works fine

# empty list
output <- list()

# for loop - go through each flagging column
for (i in (length(mydataset1)-4):length(mydataset1)) {
  output[[i]] <- get_table(mydataset1, "column_000")
}

# for some reason, there are NULL list items for all other columns
output <- compact(output)

# rename and print
names(output) <- names(mydataset1)[(length(mydataset1)-4):length(mydataset1)]
print(output)
```

This is what I have for now.
If I execute the contents of `output_list` function manually, it works fine.
However, if I execute it as a function, it gives me an error that object `i` is not found.

Where did I get it wrong? Please help!

Comment: Please provide some data to make this post reproducible. Edit your post to include `dput(mydataset1)`.

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks! Adding the dummy dataset clarified the issue for me too. Hope it is easier for others to examine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `i` as an input to `get_table` function.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

get_table <- function(data, column, i) {
  
  data %>%
    # select the flag
    filter(data[[i]] == 1) %>% 
    # summary table
    tabyl(column) %>%
    arrange(desc(n)) %>%
    top_n(5, n)
  
}
```

Make the corresponding changes in `output_list` function.

```
output_list <- function(data, column) {
  # empty list
  output <- list()
  
  # for loop - go through each flagging column
  for (i in (length(data)-4):length(data)) {
    output[[i]] <- get_table(data, column, i)
  }
  
  # for some reason, there are NULL list items for all other columns
  output <- compact(output)
  
  # rename and print
  names(output) <- names(data)[(length(data)-4):length(data)]
  print(output)
  
  
}
```

Run the function -

```
output_list(mydataset1, "column_000")
```

Comment: Thank you! It makes so much sense now. Feel silly for not being able to see it when it was right there! (:

Answer (score 0):

In your get table function, you are using "i" but not declaring "i" in the function argument. Your code works fine when you run code separately because i value gets assigned from the for loop in the global environment. if you intend to use i from for loop in get_table function you can just declare it. See code below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

## mydataset1

mydataset1 <- tibble(id = 1:100,
                     column_000 = sample(1:16, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     flag1 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     flag2 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     flag3 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     flag4 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE),
                     flag5 = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE)) 




## summary table function

get_table <- function(data, column) {

data %>%
  # select the flag
  filter(data[[i]] == 1) %>%

  # summary table
  tabyl(column) %>%
  arrange(desc(n)) %>%
  top_n(5, n)

}



## list of tables function

output_list <- function(data, column) {


  # empty list
  output <- list()

  # for loop - go through each flagging column
  for (i in (length(data)-4):length(data)) {
    output[[i]] <- get_table(data, column)
  }

  # for some reason, there are NULL list items for all other columns
  output <- compact(output)
  
  # rename and print
  names(output) <- names(data)[(length(data)-4):length(data)]
  print(output)


}


### execute

output_list(mydataset1, "column_000")
# error


### manually executing the function works fine

# empty list
output <- list()

# for loop - go through each flagging column
for (i in (length(mydataset1)-4):length(mydataset1)) {
  output[[i]] <- get_table(mydataset1, "column_000")
}

# for some reason, there are NULL list items for all other columns
output <- compact(output)

# rename and print
names(output) <- names(mydataset1)[(length(mydataset1)-4):length(mydataset1)]
print(output)
```